# How can I increase my available Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

I presently have only 180 of 250 available pokemon.  According to my son's iPad, he presently has 229 of 1,000 available pokemon.  When my eggs hatch, I get the same ones over and over again. When his eggs hatch, he gets a new one every time.

How can I increase my available pokemon from 250 to 1,000?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  My question is, we can buy pokemon storage upgrades until we're blue in the face.  If there are only 850 total available pokemon, it would make no sense to keep upgrading until you have the ability to store 1,000 pokemon.  How many available pokemon are there then?  Surely a lot more than 250!!!!

Comment: Pokemon Go is only up to 2nd Gen. Including the Pokemon that haven't been released from those 2 generations, the number of available Pokemon is only 251

Comment: @FrancisFarren The reason for being able to upgrade storage so much is so that you can store all the available Pokemon plus a few duplicates of your strongest one. For example, Havig 3 Dragonite, 2 Charizard, etc.

Comment: To add to @AssafiCohen-Arazi: there can be many goals in Pokemon Go. One is catching all different pokemon, another would be having the best pokemon, controlling gyms etc. At least for most catching all different is a goal, this goal is easier to achieve with better pokemon (hence the need for more space than pokemons available); with better pokemons raid bosses are more easily defeated, controlling gyms allows you to earn coins to buy space, incubators etc. Leveling your player up also gives you better pokemons as do catching enough all types of pokemon to add to your chance of catching them.

Answer (score 4):

You can upgrade your Pokemon Box capacity in the Shop. You will need 200 coins. Each upgrade expands capacity by 50.

[image]

As far as the eggs, it's just luck of the draw.

Answer (score 1):

By your comment is seems that you are asking how many different Pokemon can you possibly encounter, not how many Pokemon can you store at any one time.

In that case currently only Generation 1 and 2 Pokemon are available (a total of 251), however there are a small handful of those 251 which are currently not available or require special circumstances to find or catch.

The list of Pokemon currently available are found [here](https://serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon.shtml).

Certain ones like #83 Farfetch'd are only seen in Asia, (a few other Pokemon are specific to certain continents or longitude/latitude zones)

The legendary birds from generation one (Zapdos, Articuno, and Moltres), where only available in specific raids, and only for a limited period of time (until the end of August 2017), so as of now they are currently not available.

A few of the 251 are also not currently available simply because they haven't been added into the game yet: See #235 Smeargle.

As of my count right now, assuming you've managed to catch all 3 legendary birds while they where available, it is possible to have a total of 247 different Pokemon.

Yes, there are many more Pokemon in future generations, but as now, none of them have been added to Pokemon Go.